# How to transfer data (dynamically allocated using malloc) from device to host in cuda?

Tags: cuda

I have the below linked list implementation where I am invoking malloc inside a kernel. Now I need to see the result in the host machine. Basically I need to transfer whatever I created in the device to be transferred to the host.

I looked into few implementations but din't get the clear idea.

```
struct SlabList{
        int val[SLAB_SIZE];
        int key[SLAB_SIZE];
        struct SlabList* next;
};
__global__ void insertKernel(struct SlabList* head_ref, int* new_key, int* new_val, int size){
        int id = blockIdx.x*blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
        if(id==0){
        head_ref=NULL;
        for(int i=0;i<size/4;i++){
                struct SlabList* new_node = (struct SlabList*) malloc(sizeof(struct SlabList));
                for(int j=0;j<SLAB_SIZE;j++){
                        new_node->key[j] = new_key[i*SLAB_SIZE+j];
                        new_node->val[j]= new_val[i*SLAB_SIZE+j];
                        printf("key--->%d\tVal---->%d\n",new_node->key[j],new_node->val[j]);
                }
                new_node->next = head_ref;
                head_ref    = new_node;
        }
}

int main(void){
int *val_array = (int *)malloc(N * sizeof(int));
        int *key_array = (int *)malloc(N * sizeof(int));
        int *d_val_array = NULL;
        int *d_key_array = NULL;
        int *device_array;
        struct SlabList *start=(struct SlabList*)malloc(sizeof(struct SlabList));
        struct SlabList *d_start=(struct SlabList*)malloc(sizeof(struct SlabList));
        cudaMalloc(&d_val_array, N * sizeof(int));
        cudaMalloc(&d_key_array, N * sizeof(int));
        struct Slab* new_node = (struct Slab*) malloc(sizeof(struct Slab));
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++){
                val_array[i] =i;
                key_array[i] =i+10;
        }
        cudaMemcpy(d_val_array, val_array, N * sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
        cudaDeviceSetLimit(cudaLimitMallocHeapSize, sizeof(struct SlabList)*N);
        cudaMemcpy(d_key_array, key_array, N * sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
        const clock_t begin_time1 = clock();
        insertKernel<<<1, 1>>>(d_start, d_val_array,d_key_array, N);
//      insertKernel<<<32, 32>>>();
        cudaDeviceSynchronize();
        struct SlabList* head1 = NULL;
        cudaMemcpy(head1, d_start, N * sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
```

Comment: `insertKernel(..){
        head_ref=NULL;
        for(int i=0;i<size/4;i++){
                //SAME AS ABOVE
                new_node->next = head_ref;
                head_ref    = new_node;
                memcpy(temp,new_node, size * sizeof(struct SlabList));
                memcpy(SL,temp, size * sizeof(struct SlabList));
                SL = SL->next;
                memcpy(SL,temp, size * sizeof(struct SlabList));
        }
        SL->next =NULL;
 }`     How can I get the entire linked list transferred to the host. Could please help me out. @RobertCrovella

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to transfer data from a region allocated by in-kernel `malloc` directly to host memory.  The reason for this is [mentioned in the programming guide](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#dynamic-global-memory-allocation-and-operations).  Data regions allocated by in-kernel `malloc` or in-kernel `new` or in-kernel `cudaMalloc` are allocated out of a special region called the device heap.

Addresses in the device heap cannot participate in any host-based `cudaMemcpy`-type API.  Only addresses in host memory or addresses resulting from a host based device allocator such as `cudaMalloc`, `cudaHostAlloc`, or `cudaMallocManaged` may participate in the host `cudaMemcpy` -type APIs.

Therefore the only solution is:

1. Provide an allocation using the host-based API (e.g. `cudaMalloc`, `cudaHostAlloc`, `cudaMallocManaged`)
2. In device code, copy the data from the region allocated by in-kernel `malloc` to the region allocated in step 1 above.
3. Use an ordinary host-based copy API if needed (e.g. `cudaMemcpy`, but not explicitly needed if the region in step 1 is allocated with either `cudaHostAlloc` or `cudaMallocManaged`), to copy the data from the region allocated in step 1 to the host.

Comment: `insertKernel(..){
        head_ref=NULL;
        for(int i=0;i<size/4;i++){
                //SAME AS ABOVE
                new_node->next = head_ref;
                head_ref    = new_node;
                memcpy(temp,new_node, size * sizeof(struct SlabList));
                memcpy(SL,temp, size * sizeof(struct SlabList));
                SL = SL->next;
                memcpy(SL,temp, size * sizeof(struct SlabList));
        }
        SL->next =NULL;
 }`     How can I get the entire linked list transferred to the host. Could please help me out. @RobertCrovella